# OpenGL: Sampler2D bound, but empty

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm trying to bind a texture to a uniform sampler2D in the fragment shader of my program, but when I read from the texture all I get is black. I've then used a graphical debugger called RenderDoc to examine the texture I upload and interestingly enough RenderDoc finds the texture, confirms that it is bound and that it contains what I expect it to contain.

Here is what I do, in the order I do it:

Creating the texture using glTexImage2D:

```
GLuint m_buffers[2];
glGenTextures(2, this->m_buffers);


glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->_m_buffers[0]);
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,                      //Mipmaps
    GL_RGBA,                //Internal format
    this->m_texture_width,
    this->m_texture_height,
    0,                      //Border
    GL_RGBA,                //Format read
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,       //Type of values in read format
    NULL                    //source
);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);       //When shrunk go blurry
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);       //When enlarged go blurry
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);    //Set wrapping to clamp to edge
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);    //Set wrapping to clamp to edge
```

Fixing a uniform in shader (uniform_name is "texture_computed0")

```
GLint uniLoc = glGetUniformLocation(this->m_program, uniform_name.c_str());
if(uniLoc == (GLint)-1) {
   //If it does not, write out an error
   std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::" << uniform_name << "::UNIFORM_NOT_FOUND" << std::endl;
}
```

Binding the texture to texture unit 6 (COMPUTE_TEX)

```
Bind2DTextureTo(this->m_buffers[0], COMPUTE_TEX);
```

using this function

```
enum TextureEnums {
 POS_TEX,        //0
 NOR_TEX,        //1
 DIFFSPEC_TEX,   //2
 LGTPOS_TEX,     //3
 MESHDIFF_TEX,   //4
 MESHSPEC_TEX,   //5
 COMPUTE_TEX,    //6
 DEPTH_TEX,      //7
 NUM_OF_TEX
};

inline void Bind2DTextureTo(GLuint texture_id, TextureEnums target_unit) {
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + target_unit);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
}
```

Then receiving it in the fragment shader like:

```
layout (binding=6) uniform sampler2D texture_computed0;
```

And finally trying to use it:

```
out_col = texture(texture_computed0, v_uvs);
```

Now `out_col` is a `vec4` that is drawn onto the screen and trying to get colors from other textures works perfectly fine. I then went into RenderDoc which shows me that the texture *texture_diffuse0* is bound to texture unit 6, it has the right proportions, has the format `rgba8` as expected and if i open the bound texture in RenderDoc I can see the texture that I expect to see on the screen.

So I get a black screen but the debugging program tells me nothing is wrong. Has anyone seen something similar?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I have another couple of textures bound to other texture units that I can retrieve the correct data from using my uv coordinates ``v_uvs``.

Comment: I think the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` being just `GL_LINEAR` should avoid this, but I wonder if it's because you're lacking mip levels and the texture is somehow treated as incomplete. RenderDoc will display even incomplete textures, and currently doesn't check/alert for this. See [the OpenGL wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#Texture_completeness) for more information, but you could test this by adding `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);`

Comment: I've tried adding``glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);`` but cannot see anything changing. It seems that is covered by the ``GL_TEXTURE_MIN/MAG_FILTER`` set to ``GL_LINEAR``